# swig to hbs for search results

Tags: handlebars.js, swig

Im relatively new to handlebars but am using it for a current project.

I need to show search results which I would usually show like this in swig:

```
{% for loan in data.loans %}
    {% include 'loan.swig' %}
{% endfor %}
```

but that obviously won't work in hbs.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to what I should be putting?

Much appreciated.